# Titanium studio how do i submit a text field?

Tags: titanium-mobile

I am developing a mobile app in titanium studio and cannot get a text field to submit natively

this is my code:

```
  var textField1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
  borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
  color: '#336699',
  width: 250, height: 60
  });

   textField1.addEventListener('return', function(data) {
   alert('form submitted: ' + data);
   });

  win1.add(textField1);
```

I am new to titanium studio but i believe this should work.
any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

return is fired only when return button is pressed. so i think you can get the values whenever textbox has lost focus.

you can get value by :

```
textField1.addEventListener('blur',function(data){
    alert(data.source.value);
});
```

more details can be found using `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

But this will not be fired for 'return' listener. so you can also include same code for 'return' too.

```
textField1.addEventListener('return',function(data){
    alert(data.source.value);
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:"Configuring text field and text area keyboard types",
    backgroundColor:"#347AA9",
    exitOnClose:true
});

var submitButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:"Submit",
    height:24,
    width:60
});

var textField = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    top:"25%",
    height:35,
    width:600,
    backgroundColor:"#ffffff",
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    hintText:"Type something",
    keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
    rightButton:submitButton
});

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    //Pretend to submit the value of the text field
    //Be sure that you've typed something in!
    if(textField.value != ""){
        alert(textField.value); 
    }else{
        alert("Enter some text");
    }
});

//Add an event listener to the window that allows for the keyboard or input keys to be hidden if the user taps outside a text field
//Note: each text field to be blurred would be added below
win.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    textField.blur(); // Cause the text field to lose focus, thereby hiding the keyboard (if visible)
});

win.add(textField);

win.open();
```